# Angular way popup not showing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It's working in header but in content when I switch between `Callback.isCollapsed = !Callback.isCollapsed` it's not switching these two blocks.

It's showing the same block.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse navbar-menu" data-ng-show="!headerCollapse.isCollapsed">
<div class="navigation-inner-req" data-ng-show="Callback.isCollapsed">
</div>
<div class="navigation-inner-req" data-ng-hide="Callback.isCollapsed">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle

Comment: This could be because of change in scope. Can you provide a jsfiddle or paste more descriptive code ?